# Hoping for a cleaner way to get a boolean array by row based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The task is simple.

If all column values (say Columns C, E:I) are not zero and no specific text in a column (say Column B), then return no data for that row.

The result should be returned as array for further evaluation.

[image: Illustration]

I know how to be done by applying the following code to column J:

```
=IF(
  --(INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)="Show me")+
  --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("C1:C"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))))+
  --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("E1:E"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))))+
  --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("F1:F"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))))+
  --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("G1:G"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))))+
  --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("H1:H"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))))+
  --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("I1:I"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))))+
  --(INDIRECT("C1:C"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0)+
  --(INDIRECT("E1:E"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0)+
  --(INDIRECT("F1:F"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0)+
  --(INDIRECT("G1:G"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0)+
  --(INDIRECT("H1:H"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0)+
  --(INDIRECT("I1:I"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0),
"Have data","No data")
```

However, the formula is super clumsy and slow.

Shortened by using "Let" is not a option because of older Excel.

I am hoping for any other cleaner way to handle this.

Comment: Why aren't you checking by row instead of columns?

Comment: Please note that the checking in J is based on each row.

Comment: An attempt to summarise what the formula is doing, which is very complicated:  In a row, if B contains "Show me", or if C, D, E, F, G, H and I contain anything other than zero, then return "Have Data". For a row to return "No Data", it must have zero in columns B, C, D, E, F, G, H and I, and it must also not have "Show me" in B.

Comment: The mechanism appears to works as follows: 1) Look for "Show me" in column B; [FORMULA: --(INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)="Show me")+] 2) Count whether a cell in each row is not a number, in columns B, C,D,E,F,G,H and I (Note that a blank cell qualifies here) [FORMULA: --(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("C1:C"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1))));] 3) Count whether each row is not a zero, in columns B, C,D,E,F,G,H and I [FORMULA: --(INDIRECT("H1:H"&MATCH("End",$A:$A,0)-1)<>0)]; 4) Return "Have Data" if the count is greater than zero [FORMULA: IF... "Have data","No data")]

Comment: How about the following, in column J? =IF(A1<>"End",IF(B1="Show me", "Have Data", IF(COUNTIF(C1:I1,0)-6,"Have Data","No Data")), "")

Comment: @Luke Sharkey
 Thank you for your comments. My first attempt to develop the formula is to use countif. However, after browsing around, I found that countif is not going to return array type response. As I mentioned in the question, I hope array can be returned from the formula. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I provided an [answer to your `IF` test](https://superuser.com/a/1759091/).  Not sure what you mean about returning an array.  Is there more that needs to be added to your question?  Shouldn't the array be in place of the "No Data" or "Have data" placeholders?

Comment: @Blind Spots
 Sorry for my poor english. The answer you provided is requiring to be pasted at cell J1 and fill down to cell J5. The code I provided in the question can work by pasting at cell J1 and do not need to fill down to work because the formula returned array format. Hope this explanation is understandable. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, what benefit does that give you?  The indirect functions are causing the problem.  I don't get it?  If you can't use sheets and you can't use current versions of Excel maybe just convert range to a table then you can use named cells and they will auto populate and update on changes.

Comment: Updated answer to include a table version so you don't need to copy and paste formulas down columns on old versions of Excel

Comment: Noticed my first comment should have omitted column "D".

Answer (score 1):

This formula will return `TRUE` only if `B1 = "Show me"` AND each column in the range `C1, E1:I1` contain the number `0`

```
=IF(AND(B1<>"Show me",
        ISNUMBER(C1),
        ISNUMBER(E1:I1),
        SUM(C1, E1:I1)=0),
    "No Data",
    "Have Data"
)
```

<kbd>Table Version</kbd>
<kbd>[image: table version]</kbd>

Comment: After detailed testing and transformed to non-table version, (=IF((
                   (B1:B6<>"Show me")+
                   (ISNUMBER(C1:C6))+
                   (ISNUMBER(E1:E6))+
                   (ISNUMBER(F1:F6))+
                   (ISNUMBER(G1:G6))+
                   (ISNUMBER(H1:H6))+
                   (ISNUMBER(I1:I6))+
                   (SUM(C1:C6,E1:I6)=0)
          ),"No Data","Have Data")) ,   I found that the problem of the formula is (SUM(C1:C6,E1:I6)=0) return 1 non-array format. Therefore, I guess the formula is not working with non-table version. Thank you.